# scanf doesn't store proper information in structure

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have a problem with `scanf`. `scanf` doesn't store proper information in structure. Part of code is:

```
if( figure->pro.p_category == 'C' || figure->pro.p_category == 'c' ){
    printf("Enter data line> ");
    result += scanf("%s %d%c %d %d %d%c", (figure->pro.name), &temp,\
    &figure->pro.money, &figure->exp.month, &figure->exp.year,\
    &figure->ais.aisle_num, &figure->ais.aisle_side);
    if ( figure->pro.money == 'C')
        figure->pro.cents = temp;
    else if( figure->pro.money == 'D')
        figure->pro.dollars = temp;
}
```

`figure->pro.name` and `figure->exp.month` store different values.

My structures are:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    char p_category,
        sub_p_category,
        money;
    int cents,
        dollars;
}product_t;

typedef struct {
    int aisle_num;
    char aisle_side;
}aisle_t;

typedef struct {
    int day,
        month,
        year;
}experiment_t;

typedef struct {
    int day,
        month,
        year;
}packaging_t;

typedef union {
    product_t pro;
    experiment_t exp;
    packaging_t pack;
    aisle_t ais;
}figure_t;
```

For instance;

```
input> corn 89C 11 2010 11B
```

This piece of code from output function:

```
printf("The %s costs %d cents, expires in ",my_figure.pro.name, my_figure.pro.cents);

            print_exp_month(my_figure);
            printf("of %d, and is displayed in %d%c", my_figure.exp.year, my_figure.ais.aisle_num,\
            my_figure.ais.aisle_side);
```

its output:

> The
>
> costs 89 Dollar, expires in of 2000, and is displayed in 12B

The proper output:

> The corn costs 89 cents, expires in November of 2000, and is displayed in 12B

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would help us a great deal if you could tell us which information exactly is "not properly stored", and what exactly constitutes "not properly stored". Also, you may want to simplify your problem. If you just `scanf("%s", (figure->pro.name));`, does the problem persist?

Comment: "ctype.h", tolower()/toupper().

Comment: You don't need '\' at the end of wrapped lines in C.  You only need them for preprocessor directives which span multiple lines.

Comment: My input is corn.But, it stores only blanks

Comment: Don't typedef the structs.  They have a type already.  All you're doing is making your code less simple and straightforward.

Comment: I can't see (did I miss it?) an example of the input.  We need to see that to see if the scanf() format string is correct.

Comment: Note: `scanf` with `%s` is dangerous unless you specify an appropriate field width., e.g. `%19s`.

Comment: Be consistent with formatting - you have one "if()" and one "if ()".

Comment: @Charles: I concur, but I think in this case, it should read up to the first whitespace and stop?  it should be okay here (although that may depend on the input string).

Comment: @guguk: your input is "corn"?  what do you mean?  you are literally entering the string "corn" as input?

Comment: @Blank_Xavier    

 
`scanf("%s %d%c %d %d %d%c", (figure->pro.name), &temp,\
    &figure->pro.money, &figure->exp.month, &figure->exp.year,\
    &figure->ais.aisle_num, &figure->ais.aisle_side);`
my input is "corn 89C 11 2010 11B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your data in a union

```
typedef union {
    product_t pro;
    experiment_t exp;
    packaging_t pack;
    aisle_t ais;
} figure_t;
```

only one set of data is stored at each time. When you read into, for example, `figure->pro.money` and `figure->exp.month` the data will be stored in the same place and overwrite each other.

So when you try to print it, it is not there anymore!